# pbzip2 large file does not utilize resources

Tags: compression

I'm trying to use pbzip2 on a multicore system to speed up decompression of a ~10GB file.  It was zipped with regular bzip2.  When I try to decompress with pbzip2 -p3 it doesn't take more resources.  Suggestions?

Comment: What does "it doesn't take more resources" mean?

Comment: Use more cores/memory.